# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im building a react website which will fetch data from the newsapi and display on cards. On checking whether there's a length in which after, it will display or display an alternative response, am getting this error. 
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Heres whats ive coded:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class Cards extends Component {
 constructor () {
   super();
   this.state = {
     post: [
 {
         author:"",
         discription:"",
         publishedAt:"",
         title:"",
         urlToImage:""
       }
]
   };
 }

componentDidMount() {
fetch('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?' +
      'country=us&' +
      'apiKey=GIVEN API KEY')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => this.setState({post :response}));
}
  render() {
    const { post } = this.state;
    const postlist = post.length ? (
      post.map(post => {
        return (
          <div>
            <div class="container card mb-3">
              <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <img src={post.urlToImage} class="card-img" alt="..."/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">{post.title}</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">{post.description}</p>
                    <div class="row">
                      <p class="card-text col-6"><small class="text-muted">{post.author}</small></p>
                      <p class="card-text col-6"><small class="text-muted">{post.publishedAt}</small></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })
    )
    : (
      <div class="center">No post yet!</div>
    );


    return (
      <div class="container">
        <h2>Latest News</h2>
        {postlist}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Cards;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error when destructuring `this.state`. `const { post } = this.state.post;` should be `const { post } = this.state;`.

EDIT
From https://newsapi.org it looks like the structure of the response will be `{status: ..., totalArticles: ..., articles: [...]}`. So your `componentDidMount` should be:

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?' +
      'country=us&' +
      'apiKey=GIVEN API KEY')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => this.setState({post :response.articles}));
}
```

Comment: Led to another error "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.setstate is not a function"

Comment: the correct function is `this.setState`, not `this.setstate`

Comment: Okay, now theres an error with the map. "TypeError: post.map is not a function".

Comment: Your fetch call must be populating state.post with something other than an array when it completes

Comment: Have made all the stated corrections and now it's working, but is showing the "else" statement, rather than the news post. You could see that the data was being loaded when you check your browser react developer tool. Reviewed the code several times but cant seem to find any thing.

Comment: Can you console.log and share the value of `post` from the `render` function after the fetch call completes? My hunch the response is an object instead of an array so `post.length` is undefined and you're getting the else block of the ternary.

Comment: @KelvinYelyen see the edit to my post above to correct for the proper response structure.

Comment: Worked!! Thanks.